# How to target elements in nested ControlTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

In the style for my custom combobox I want to change the `Background` property of the `Border` element in the `ToggleButton`'s `ControlTemplate` when the `ComboBox.IsEditable` property is set to true but am running into this error targeting the `Border`:

> Cannot find the Trigger target.  (The target must appear before any Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that use it.)

**Things I've tried:**

- Targeting the Border by it's name: `TargetName="Border"`
- Targeting the Border as a child of the ToggleButton: `TargetName="ToggleButton.Border"`

The only information I can find online says:

> TargetName operates only within the one ControlTemplate section

But I'm not sure if this is relevant to my situation since the `ToggleButtons`'s `ControlTemplate` is a child of my custom combobox's `ControlTemplate`.

**Style** (irrelevant code removed for brevity)

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="False" ClickMode="Press"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                            Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomComboBox}}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>                 
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ToggleButton.Border" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: There is no `Border` property in ToggleButton. Anyways, in this case, you don't need `TargetName="ToggleButton.Border"`.

Comment: @emoacht Border is the name of the Border **element** in the ToggleButton's ControlTemplate. Please explain how I change the Background property of the Border element without targeting it in the trigger?

Comment: If `TargetName` is not given, the target will be local:CustomComboBox itself. And you set a binding between Border.Background of "Border" and local:CustomComboBox.Background. Accordingly, this trigger will change local:CustomComboBox.Background and then the value will be reflected to  Border.Background of "Border". That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting a value on a nested template, do it the other way around, bind the `IsEditable` property of the parent `CustomComboBox` in the nested template via a [relative source binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=net-5.0). Use a `DataTrigger` to set the color of the `Border` to `Green` in case the property is `True`.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
            <Grid>
               <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="False" ClickMode="Press"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                  <ToggleButton.Template>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Grid>
                           <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomComboBox}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomComboBox}}" Value="True">
                              <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                           </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </ToggleButton.Template>
               </ToggleButton>                 
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank for your help, this solved my problem completely. Also, thank you for taking the time to edit my question to show me what was wrong with it and why I was being downvoted.